# How to scrape Japanese content using Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapy

I have a code in Python requests and also tried in Python Scrapy.

It returns correct HTML but the content inside HTML tags is strange characters like `Á¶¼±°úÇÐ±â¼úÃÑ·Ã¸Í Áß¾ÓÀ§¿øÈ¸ Á¶¼±ÀÚµ¿È­ÇÐÈ¸¿Í Á¶¼±ÀÚ¿¬¿¡³` etc.

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'If-Modified-Since': 'Mon, 22 May 2017 16:51:07 GMT',
    'If-None-Match': '"269-5501fad6c02b2-gzip"',
    'Referer': 'http://kcna.co.jp/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get('http://kcna.co.jp/item2/2001/200107/news07/01.htm#10', headers=headers, verify=False)

resp = HtmlResponse(url='',body=response.text, encoding='utf8')
print(resp.css('p::text').get().encode('utf8').decode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents are in Korean, not Japanese. The site is run by the Korean News Service branch in Tokyo, a North Korean Government news agency, I believe.

The page itself doesn't declare the encoding, so the default encoding for HTML4 is being used: ISO-8859-1. The content is encoded using EUC-KR, a legacy Korean encoding.

So exploring the feed:

```py
import requests
from encodings import euc_kr

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'If-Modified-Since': 'Mon, 22 May 2017 16:51:07 GMT',
    'If-None-Match': '"269-5501fad6c02b2-gzip"',
    'Referer': 'http://kcna.co.jp/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get('http://kcna.co.jp/item2/2001/200107/news07/01.htm#10', headers=headers, verify=False)

# Identify current encoding
response.encoding
# 'ISO-8859-1'

# rest encoding
response.encoding = 'euc-kr'

# Convert to bytes then back to string
rt = response.text.encode('euc-kr').decode('euc-kr')

# Alternatively using encodings module:
# Convert to bytes: response.text.encode('euc-kr')
# and convert encoding to UTF-8
rt = euc_kr.codec.decode(response.text.encode('euc-kr'))[0]
rt[0:300]
# '<html>\r\n<head><title>past news</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="#eeeeee">\r\n
# <small>\r\n\r\n<a name="1"><h4>김영남위원장\u3000수단대통령에게\u3000축전</a></h4>\r\n\u3000
# （평양\u3000７월\u3000１일발\u3000조선중앙통신）조선민주주의인민공화국\u3000최고인민회의\u3000상임위원회\u3000김영남위원장이\u3000수단혁명절\u3000１２돐에\u3000즈음하여\u3000수단공화국\u3000대통령\u3000오마르\u3000하싼\u3000아흐마드\u3000알\u3000바쉬르에게\u3000축전을\u3000보내였다．<br>\r\n\u3000６월\u3000２９일부로\u3000된\u3000축전에는\u3000다음과\u3000같이\u3000지적되여\u3000있다．<br>\r\n\u3000나는\u3000수단혁명절\u3000１２돐에\u3000즈음하여\u3000당'
```

As can be seen data is encoded in EUC-KR.

To use with your code:

```py
import requests
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'If-Modified-Since': 'Mon, 22 May 2017 16:51:07 GMT',
    'If-None-Match': '"269-5501fad6c02b2-gzip"',
    'Referer': 'http://kcna.co.jp/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get('http://kcna.co.jp/item2/2001/200107/news07/01.htm#10', headers=headers, verify=False)

response.encoding = 'euc-kr'
resp = HtmlResponse(url='',body=response.text, encoding='euc-kr')
```

`resp` at this stage should be a Unicode string.